# Can't get "try-error" class in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I need to check my connection to database, is it expired or not:
when i try to execute query, i get such error

```
> dbGetQuery(con,"select * from users limit 1")
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
)
NULL
Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create executeselect * from users limit 1
```

Okay, i need something like "if error then print("connection expired")".
I tried to solve this problem so:

```
> class(try(dbGetQuery(con,"select * from users limit 1"), silent = T))
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
)
[1] "NULL"
Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create executeselect * from users limit 1
```

And got this error and warning again. And class of that try expressions is "NULL", not "try-error". 
But when i do this:

```
> class(try(log("hi"), silent = T))
[1] "try-error"
```

I've got no errors and try-error class

Why?

UPD.
Solved this problem via

```
>options(warn = 2, show.error.messages = F)
```

And then

```
class(try(dbGetQuery(con,"select * from users limit 1"), silent = T))
[1] "try-error"
```

Comment: Isn't the bigger problem that you can't connect properly to your Postgres database?  Do you want help with that?

Comment: nope, there is 2-hours timeout for open connections, so i can just reconnect=)

Comment: Aren't you missing a schema in your query?  Shouldn't be something like `select * from schema.users limit 1` ?  This assumes that you can actually connect.

Comment: You are silencing the error...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen   tried, same errors and warnings, "NULL" class, not "try-error"

Comment: Get the query working on Postgres, and then go back to R.  Also verify that the connection actually works.

Comment: Can it be that the error is already captured in `dbGetQuery`? I.e `dbGetQuery` doesn't actually generate an error.

Comment: Looking at `getMethod("dbGetQuery", signature=c("DBIConnection", "character"))`, the error is indeed captured in `dbGetQuery`.

Comment: So, perhaps, a `suppresWarnings` around the `dbGetQuery` call and then check for a `NULL` return value.